# Taking means of different columns based on column in different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have two data frames - one has metadata for the main matrix. One of the columns in the metadata matrix contains replicate variables, one with 6, the rest with three as follows:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[1,] A1  D1  name1
[2,] A2  D1  name2
[3,] A3  D3  name3
[4,] A4  D3  name4
[5,] A5  D3  name5
```

The other data frame has the columns named after the values in column [,1] above, and then a series of values in each row. I am looking to average the columns in Dataframe 2 based on the values in column [,2] of dataframe 1 that correspond to the values in the column names of dataframe 2. So for instance, to get the average of D1 responses in dataframe 2, I would need to average A1 and A2. My problem is that I have quite a large dataset with different numbers of Dx replicates.
Dataframe two looks like this:

```
    [A1][A2][A3][A4][A5]
[1,] 32  31  45  47  46
[2,] 12  14  24  23  26
[3,] 24  24  57  54  56
```

Comment: Please expand your answer to include "the other data frame" and what the result of that example would look like.

Comment: Should be clearer now